# Other preconfigured service hosting platform like Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, service, hosting

I'm finding alternatives for Google App Engine for startup. The **preconfigured** service hosting include security, networking, scaling, database, backup, application, maturity and etc.. Because we have no experts on each parts. It's too hard operating whole service stack properly for only one application programmer.

What other services can I consider for this?

Comment: what language do you want to use? most of them are language specific.

Comment: @Jason C# or Java are first candidate. Others are all secondary. However I don't care about languages seriously. I'm not a guru, but learning a new language or framework should be easier learning how to operate whole service stack properly for application programmer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term you want to search for is PaaS or Platform-as-a-Service. I do not claim to be an expert in this nacent field, however my basic understanding of the key players other than Google App Engine are:

- [Amazon AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/) - My understanding is that Amazon's Web Services gives you bare-bones OS installs that you can completely own. While this allows for more configuration than App Engine, this also means you are on the hook for patching security holes and what not.  (Right?)
- [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) - App Engine type functionality, except for Ruby
- [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com/) - App Engine type functionality, except for .NET
- [Microsoft Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/) - Amazon AWS type functionality, except for Windows/The Microsoft stack.

Comment: Should mention Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk, which is the PaaS version of Amazon's Elastic Compute Cloud. http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

Comment: Amazon AWS is a large collection of web services that do various things. I think that you mean Amazon EC2 -- Elastic Compute Cloud. It gives you a virtual machine that runs on Amazon's infrastructure. Microsoft Azure is *much* closer to AppEngine than EC2. You do not get a virtual machine; you deploy programs that are written to a specific set of APIs, like AppEngine.

Answer (score 0):

[The CloudCamp awards 2011](https://cloudcamp.uservoice.com/forums/106309-top-paas) serves as a nice list of PaaS services